# How to setup internal DNS on Windows?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I just created a couple of Active Directory Servers for a company, as we all know Active Directory has its own DNS server embedded, I created a new forest and called it example.local, the company has an internal web server for their web apps and they want these apps to have internal names, not available for public, so I created a new zone in AD DNS called example.com, added the external NS for it and added their internal web apps to it.

Here is the problem, the internal sites are working just fine, but when somebody in the company tries to go to example.com for their "external" website, the DNS cannot find it, even though it has the external Name Servers in it.

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked/discussed in numerous previous questions. The upshot is there cannot be any overlap in the domain name or records internally or externally. I.e., don't use the same domain name internally for AD if it is in use externally.

Comment: I would create two DNS zones, an internal and an external, make a conditional forwarder on the internal zone for the external zone.Ideally host the external zone on a different server more hardened.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it, added an empty A record with the external IP and it's working now.